# How to move Tkinter ScrolledText widget and stop it from shifting all the other widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to have the ScrolledText widget moved to the right of the screen but I am not sure how to do this. Additionally how can I stop the widget from shifting everything else down? I am still very new to using tkinter and im honestly not too sure what I am doing.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:
[image]

And here is my code for this:

```
user = POSMachine()
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

pos = Tk()
pos.title("POS Machine")
pos.geometry("1000x550")

def priceListInput():
    option1Entry = Entry(pos)
    def priceList():
        user.setPriceList(option1Entry.get())
    setListButton = Button(pos, text = "Enter", command = lambda: [priceList(), 
removeOption1Widgets(option1Entry, setListButton)])
    option1Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    setListButton.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

def printList():
    option2Label = Label(pos, text = "{}".format(user.printPriceList()))
    option2Label.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

def addTransaction():
    idLabel = Label(pos, text = "Product ID: ")
    idEntry = Entry(pos)
    quantityLabel = Label(pos, text = "Quantity: ")
    quantityEntry = Entry(pos)
    enterdetails = Button(pos, text = "Enter")

    idLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 1) 
    idEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    quantityLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    quantityEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
    enterdetails.grid(row = 3, column = 5)

def removeOption1Widgets(widget1, widget2):
    widget1.grid_remove()
    widget2.grid_remove()

def removeOption3Widgets():
    print("no")

def close():
    def exit():
        closeWindow.destroy()
        pos.destroy()
    def notExit():
        closeWindow.destroy()

    closeWindow = Tk()
    closeWindow.title("Close Window")
    closeWindow.geometry("300x100")

    label = Label(closeWindow, text = "Are you sure?")
    yesButton = Button(closeWindow, text = "Yes", command = exit, width = 10)
    noButton = Button(closeWindow, text = "No", command = notExit, width = 10)

    label.pack(side=TOP)
    yesButton.pack(side=TOP)
    noButton.pack(side=TOP)
                   
welcomeLabel = Label(pos, text = "Welcome to 7Evelyn")
option1Button = Button(pos, text = "Set Price List", command = priceListInput, width = 20)
option2Button = Button(pos, text = "View Price List", command = printList, width = 20)
option3Button = Button(pos, text = "New Transaction", command = addTransaction, width = 20,)
option4Button = Button(pos, text = "Sales Report", width = 20)
option5Button = Button(pos, text = "Close", command = close, width = 20)
display = ScrolledText(pos, width = 50)

welcomeLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
option1Button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
option2Button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
option3Button.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
option4Button.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
option5Button.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
display.grid(row = 0, column = 10)

pos.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put those label and buttons in a frame and use `pack()` on the frame and `display` to put them at the desired side.

```py
...
frame = Frame(pos)
frame.pack(side='left', fill='y')

welcomeLabel = Label(frame, text = "Welcome to 7Evelyn")
option1Button = Button(frame, text = "Set Price List", command = priceListInput, width = 20)
option2Button = Button(frame, text = "View Price List", command = printList, width = 20)
option3Button = Button(frame, text = "New Transaction", command = addTransaction, width = 20,)
option4Button = Button(frame, text = "Sales Report", width = 20)
option5Button = Button(frame, text = "Close", command = close, width = 20)
display = ScrolledText(pos, width = 50)

welcomeLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
option1Button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
option2Button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
option3Button.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
option4Button.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
option5Button.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
display.pack(side='right', fill='y')

pos.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]